# Is it possible to "lose" inserts if throughput is too high?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a large ETL operation on > 100,000 jsonl files. I'm using RabbitMQ to insert filepaths into a queue and then using 25 workers to transform the files and perform batch inserts into a number of Postgres tables.

I've noticed that if I crank the number of workers up, I may end up with less data at the end, but no errors pop up.

Is it possible to "overload" the database instance and lose data?

Notes:

- At the end, the largest table should have 2B rows
- Average table size is 250M rows
- Using the npm package `node-postgres` to handle the inserts

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible that Postgres reports a successful commit to your application without actually executing the DML statement? It is _possible_, theoretically speaking, but it's much more probable that there's an error in `node-postgres`, your code, or your data verification method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long does it take to count all those rows?

Comment: I don't think that you will ever get into the situation where Postgres silently discards data from an insert (unless you ask it to by e.g. using `on conflict do nothing`). If something goes wrong you will at least get an error

Comment: @dezso I don't even want to know. I get these tables converted to Parquet files immediately and do all the fun stuff in Spark.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to directly create the parquet files?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running with synchronous_commit off and the database crashes, it is possible that when it comes back up the most recently committed transactions will be missing.  But that is not very credible here, as if the database crashed you would almost surely know about it.

It would sever any existing connections, which would surely be noticed unless the crash happened right after the very last commit was done, and so no one tried to use a connection anymore.  (Or unless the code you are using silently ignores severed connections and just reopens them--but even then the crash would at least be noted in the PostgreSQL server log file. 
And if your code silently ignores errors, there is no limit to the number of ways you could end up with missing data)